# Qual erro é este e o que posso fazer para arruma-lo?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image: Erro de android]

> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install adb:
>   failed to install C:\pedidos\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.pedidos
>   signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!] Error
>   launching application on Mi 9 SE. Exited (sigterm)

Comment: **`Package com.example.pedidos signatures do not match previously installed version`**

Answer (score 4):

Busque entender o erro:

> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.pedidos
>   signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!]

*Falha de incompatibilidade ao instalar o update, a assinatura do teu package (Seu aplicativo) não é igual a versão já instalada; Update ignorado!*

---

Desinstale o aplicativo do seu celular e compile novamente que dará certo.

Isso as vezes ocorre quando você compila por outro computador, ou cria um outro projeto com o mesmo nome de um já previamente instalado em seu dispositivo.

**Atenção**

Fique alerta ao reinstalar, pois como seu celular é um Xiaomi irá pedir permissão para a instalação, então, quando aparecer o popup em seu celular marque a opção "Sempre permitir" e clique em Instalar.

Answer (score -2):

Aconteceu comigo recentemente mesmo sem estar instalado o app no aparelho, verifiquei que eventualmente pode ter sido mal desinstalado, o que fiz para reparar foi instalar a versão que tenho na playstore e desinstalar através do comando

```
adb uninstall 'packageName'
```

daí resolveu. Se você não tive-lo na playstore, você pode extrair o apk através de uma máquina virtual e instalá-lo no aparelho, ou ainda compilá-lo.